# pydbg can't import pydasm - Python 2.7

Tags: python, pydbg

Here is a snippets from my python shell, i can't understand what is wrong there, if somebody has any suggestion i would be glad to hear.

```
>>> import pydbg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pydbg\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pydbg                   import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pydbg\pydbg.py", line 32, in <module>
    import pydasm
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>> import pydasm
>>>
```

how come that i can't import pydbg since there it can't import pydasm, and i can import pydasm directly ?

Comment: How did you install pydbg? Usually pydbg is installed in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydbg` and pydasm.pyd in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages`.

Comment: I have installed pydbg as part of the peimai framework, and i have tried to use it with pydasm of pydbg in the pydbg directory and with a new pydasm that i have compilled but it is still does't work.

Comment: Just recompiled it myself. Seems to work. Try http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pydbg after removing the existing pydbg.

Comment: @cgohlke, Thank you, Just now i have noticed what you have wrote on the first comment, and that is true i am don't know why but my pydbg was under the `C:\Python27\lib\` directory and after moving it to the `site-packages` dir everything seems to work.

Comment: @cgohlke, put your first comment on and the link from the your last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `pydbg` directory from `C:\Python27\lib\` to `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\`, the standard installation location for 3rd party packages. Alternatively, try the unofficial pydbg binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pydbg.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by deleting pydasm.pyd in the site-packages directory for pydbg.

Answer (score 1):

Find `pydasm` for the python version you are running. I think that `pydbg` comes with `pydasm` for python2.6. I don't know why.

I found `pydasm` for python 2.7 on the Internet. You can also find information about how to convert it yourself. I am not getting any errors but I still struggle with `pydbg` so I am not sure if this is the solution.

If you are running python2.7 try this: http://blog.csdn.net/qq_lhz/article/details/6922130

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try my precompiled binaries of PyDasm for Python 2.7:

https://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/quickpost-installer-for-beaenginepython/